# Number Guessing Game in C++ without global varibles

Tags: c++, beginner, number-guessing-game

Recently, I have gotten into C++. My past experience is some batch programming and beginner JavaScript/HTML. This language, unlike the others, has made me really think about the efficiency of my code. I am trying to do a beginner exercise from a C++ [forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/) (Bracketing Searching) and make it as good as I possibly can. Can someone explain to me anything I am doing right or wrong? I also feel like this code is the most efficient, however it is really confusing to read, even for me.

```
#include <iostream> //include the input, output stream
#include <Windows.h> //include windows command library
#include <ctime> //include time library

int ask() { //ask for input and return it
    int guess;
    std::cout << "Input your guess: \n";
    std::cin >> guess;
    return guess;
}

bool calc(int guess,int num) { //takes the guess and  the number then returns true or false accordingly
    bool hasWon = false;
    if (guess > num) {
        std::cout << "Too high!\n";
    }
    else if (guess < num) {
        std::cout << "Too low!\n";
    }
    else if (guess == num) {
        std::cout << "Congrats, you are correct!\n";
        Sleep(3000);
        hasWon = true;
    }
    return hasWon;
}

void startMenu() { //Display welcome menu
    std::cout << "Welcome to my game.\n";
    std::cout << "I will think of a number from 1 to 100.\n";
    std::cout << "Guess it!\n";
}

int makeNum() {
    srand(time(0)); //Truly random number
    int num = rand() % 100; //Generate a random Number
    return num; //return the number to the main loop
}

int main() {
    startMenu(); //Display the welcome screen
    int ranNum = makeNum(); //generate the main random number
    bool hasWon = false; //set default state of win varible

    while (hasWon != true) { //while the player has NOT won keep asking
        hasWon = calc(ask(), ranNum); //Main loop of code for asking and calculating
        }
    return 0; //Terminate program
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`rand()` is bad; don't use it](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

  Instead, use the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library for generating random numbers:

  ```
  static std::mt19937_64 engine(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 100);
  std::cout << dist(engine);
  ```

  You'll then have:

  ```
  int makeNum() {
      static std::mt19937_64 engine(std::random_device{}());
      std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 100);
      return dist(engine);
  }
  ```
- The name `calc()` doesn't make sense with the expected return and it doesn't even calculate anything. You can rename it to `hasWon()` and rename the variable to `won`.

  Moreover, I would move the output to `main()` since it shouldn't really be responsible for printing to the console. Just have it do the comparison and then return the value.
- Do you really need the program to sleep? It may not be worth that call, plus it prevents it from being portable to other systems. You can always use `std::cin.get()` to "pause" the program by asking the user to enter a character before proceeding.